# Can openstack curl support v3applicationcredential authentication method?

Tags: curl, openstack

As we know we can retrieve a token with user/password from openstack and then use this token to send requests with "curl" to openstack instead of commands.
And -- to retrieve that token usually we use user/password to get it. But if it's logged in script, it will be in risk of password leaking...
In the mean time, we can use v3applicationcredential for openstack API authentication --eg. in the openrc file we can put it like --

```
vsa11061573:/home/i331281/loadbalancer/openrc # cat secret_NEO-LA-BR-1-FACTORYBR1
export OS_AUTH_URL=https://identity-3.la-br-1.cloud.sap/v3
export OS_AUTH_TYPE=v3applicationcredential
export OS_REGION_NAME=la-br-1
export OS_APPLICATION_CREDENTIAL_ID=975b3757b0704babac512ca9a80aeaa2
export OS_APPLICATION_CREDENTIAL_SECRET=MKVHS88mDv0W1KhiGQL9__UsHNuTVVfFaR-oweW-liVmljt8VkcJw4FUcA2MxAPn5ndEB__GqgwTYpV8oBWFLQ
```

But to use curl to perform openstack operation, we need to retrieve token with AUTH like this --

```
curl -i \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '
{ "auth": {
    "identity": {
      "methods": ["password"],
      "password": {
        "user": {
          "name": "user00001",
          "domain": { "name": "mydomain" },
          "password": "password0000011111"
        }
      }
    },
    "scope": {
      "project": {
        "name": "myproject",
        "domain": { "name": "mydomain" }
      }
    }
  }
}' \
  "https://identity-3.eu-de-1.cloud.sap/v3/auth/tokens"
```

Here the auth method is "Password", and in the supported list --

```
keystone.auth.plugins.external.Base
keystone.auth.plugins.mapped.Mapped
keystone.auth.plugins.oauth1.OAuth
keystone.auth.plugins.password.Password
keystone.auth.plugins.token.Token
keystone.auth.plugins.totp.TOTP
```

I can't find that v3applicationcredential -- but from https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/queens/user/application_credentials.html
we can see -- this v3applicationcredential authentication method is supported. So here's the question -- can we retrieve token with curl with this v3applicationcredential auth method? And if yes, how to get it?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards
Eisen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, everything that you can do with the openstack command line you can do with curl since they are HTTP requests in both cases.

The name of the method is `application_credential` and the required attributes are `id` and `secret`. Scope is not required since scope information is already contained within the application credential.

Inserting that information into the example you provided we get:

```bash
curl -i \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '
{ "auth": {
    "identity": {
      "methods": ["application_credential"],
      "application_credential": {
        "id": "<ID>",
        "secret": "<SECRET>"
      }
    }
  }
}' \
  "https://identity-3.eu-de-1.cloud.sap/v3/auth/tokens"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really works. Would you please share if there's any official document url for this auth method?

Comment: Your best bet is the [official API documentation and the section in it about tokens](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/identity/v3/?expanded=token-authentication-with-unscoped-authorization-detail,password-authentication-with-scoped-authorization-detail#authentication-and-token-management) and  the [official python library for authentication](https://github.com/openstack/keystoneauth/blob/6ee21bd722b3e1dbec3e5a211e32f10fb2a20603/keystoneauth1/identity/v3/application_credential.py#L48-L67).